# Best way to create android app

Tags: java, android, http

I run multiple webpages that I have programming in .net.

I am looking at learning to programming android apps (mostly because I dont have a Mac to program Iphone apps)

I'm just wondering the best way to communicate to my webpages so I have the same login and and account features on my andriod app.

Is it most commonly used HTTP protocol or do more aps use lower level TCP protocols?

Comment: Just for your info, you can communicate to your web through WebService and i think HTTP is the best.

Comment: If you just want to display web pages then [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html) is the best option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. HTTP is fine. Most of them, use HTTP only.